The plugin `audio_session` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding
The plugin audio_session uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding:
Am getting error while trying to build my flutter app

can you edit your question with adding the error message that appears
